# Executing script in other directory

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I have a script which seems to work at relative locations:

```
for x in dir1 dir2 dir3 dir4; do
  cd $x
  ./configure
  make
  cd ..
done
```

The script itself however is located somewhere else (in a mounted drive).

"dir1", "dir2", etc. however are located here:

```
LocalState/rootfs/home/myuser/dir1
LocalState/rootfs/home/myuser/dir2
```

etc.

I could now copy the script over the myuser directory, but I was wondering if I could change the script so that it uses absolute paths.

Or could I make it so that the script is executed in the myuser directory without copying it to this directory first?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have it.
I just changed the script like this:

```
for x in /home/myuser/dir1 /home/myuser/dir2 /home/myuser/dir3; do
  cd $x
  ./configure
  make
  cd ..
 done
```